# dylib on Snow Leopard "file is not of required architecture"

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I have compiled opencv on snow leopard and it says it compiled correctly, however when I try to compile my sample program against it, I get output like:

```
g++ -o tm_scons template.o -L/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lcxcore -lcv -lcvaux -lhighgui -lml
ld: warning: in /opencv/opencv/build/lib/libcxcore.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in /opencv/opencv/build/lib/libcv.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in /opencv/opencv/build/lib/libcvaux.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in /opencv/opencv/build/lib/libhighgui.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in /opencv/opencv/build/lib/libml.dylib, file is not of required architecture
```

Is this likely a problem with my compilation of OpenCV or of my app that is using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the magic was using -m32 and switching to the /usr/bin/g++-4.0 compiler.

Ugh....

Answer (score 0):

Compiling correctly does not mean compiling for whatever architecture you're trying to compile now. Most likely the library is compiled as 32-bit and you're compiling as 64-bit or vice-versa.

Comment: Do you know of an easy way to adjust the opencv compilation step to tell it to compile for 64 bit?  (I assume that is the issue?).

Comment: You can verify the architectecture of your library with the lipo command. (lipo -info /path/to/library) I think that "file" will give you this information too.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your program is compiled 64-bit (the default behavior on SnowLeopard) and the library is compiled 32-bit.  Try adding the `-m32` or `-arch i386` flag to the compiler when you build your program and see if the link works.